# Why page/events does not return event in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We obtained the following permissions. Strange though our customer can not fetch data from `page/events`. Me as admin I can. Why is the distiction?

[image]

They simply receive an empty array, though page has events.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to get the page events, the user must be admin on page